# Dynamically update observable object or type number

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable variable that i intend to dynamically update after receiving a result from another observable. My code is like below

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

let total = of(0);

observer.subscribe(x => {
  const add = (n) => + 1; 
  total.pipe(scan(add, 4)) //
  total = total.pipe(scan(add, 4)); // works but doesn't update or change total on subsequent changes.
});
```

I am kind of new to rxJS , any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the code for observer ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `BehaviorSubject` can solve your case.

```js
let total$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

observer.subscribe(x => {
  // ...
  total$.next(valueYouWantItToEmit);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrates how to dynamically accumulate a sum:

**Component**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { of, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { scan, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  amount = new Subject<number>();
  amount$ = this.amount.asObservable();

  total$ = this.amount$.pipe(
    scan((acc, amt) => acc + amt),
    tap(console.log)
  );

  doClick() {
    this.amount.next(4);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="doClick()">Add 4</button>
<p>Result: {{ total$ | async }}</p>
```

Or as previously suggested you could use a BehaviorSubject and start at 0.

You can find a working version of this code here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adder-deborahk

Also note that you shouldn't attempt to modify a stream using syntax like this:

```
myStream = myStream.pipe(...);
```

Comment: If you are interested in a tutorial, this one is free for the month of April: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/rxjs-angular-reactive-development